# Continuous Functions and Metric Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $(X, d_x)$ and $(Y, d_y)$ be metric spaces. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function.
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous (w.r.t. the metrics $d_x, d_y$) if and only if $f$ inverts closed sets to closed sets.

I know that a continuous function maps compact sets to compact sets. Would the proof for this have something to do with that? Since compact sets are closed and bounded, it makes sense that a continuous function has to map closed sets to closed sets (for the compact sets to compact sets fact to hold).

I'm a bit stuck on the closed sets to closed sets $\implies$ continuous function part. Every point in a closed set is an accumulation point; and, for a function to be continuous, whenever a real sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $p$, then $f(a_n)$ must converge to $f(p)$ as well. How do I make the connection between the RHS and LHS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A continuous function does not have to map closed sets to closed sets. And a compact subset of a metric space must be closed and bounded but a closed bounded subset of a metric space need not be compact.

Comment: (1). Let $X=\Bbb R^2$ and $Y=\Bbb R.$ Let $f(x,y)=x$ for $(x,y)\in X.$ Then $f:X\to Y$ is continuous but $ f$ maps $\{(x,1/x);0\ne x\in \Bbb R\}$ (which is closed in $X$) to $Y\setminus \{0\},$ which is not closed in $Y$........(2).  For $x,y\in \Bbb R$ let $e(x,y)=\min (1,|x-y|).$ The metric $e$ generates the same topology as the metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|,$ so $(\Bbb R,e)$ is not a compact metric space.  So with the metric $e,$ the set $\Bbb R$ is closed and bounded but  not compact.

Comment: It would help if we knew which definition of continuity you are starting with.  It is not unusual for a useful property, like continuity, to have many useful implications that are actually equivalent to the property itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with compactness.

Rather, to show the if and only if statement, first we note that $f$ inverts closed sets to closed sets if and only if $f$ inverts open sets to open sets, since we have the formula that $f^{-1}(Y-G)=X-f^{-1}(G)$.

Now observe that any open set $G$ in metric space can be written as $G=\displaystyle\bigcup_{i}B(x_{i},r_{i})$ for some open balls $B(x_{i},r_{i})$.

And we have the formula that $f^{-1}\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i} B(x_{i},r_{i})\right)=f^{-1}(B(x_{i},r_{i}))$.

Finally, for the statement like $d_{X}(y,x)<\delta\rightarrow d_{Y}(f(y),f(x))<\epsilon$ indicates that $B_{X}(x,\delta)\subseteq f^{-1}(B(f(x),\epsilon))$.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to think about compactness. Remember that a function is continuous if and only if the preimage of an open set is always open.

Suppose that for any closed set $V \subset Y$ we have that $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed. Let $U \subset Y$ be open. Then the complement $Y \setminus U$ is closed (by definition). From basic set theory (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Preimage_of_Set_Difference_under_Mapping),
$$
f^{-1}(Y \setminus U) = f^{-1}(Y) \setminus f^{-1}(U) = X \setminus f^{-1}(U)
$$
Thus $X \setminus f^{-1}(U)$ is closed, so $f^{-1}(U)$ is open. Thus $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Another definition of continuity of a function is Topological sense is that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function where $X$ and $Y$ are two Topological spaces then, for any open set $U\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in X.

Since every metric space is a Topological space so the above holds in metric space too.

Now for any closed set $F\subset Y$ we have $Y\setminus F$ is open in $Y$. By the definition $f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)$ is open in $X$ implies, $f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}(F)$ is open in $X$ implies, $X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$ open in $X$ hence, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$. Converse holds by similar arguments.